# Let $M = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots) \in l_2, x_1+x_2=0\}$. Find $M^{\perp}$. Find the decomposition $l_2=M \oplus M^{\perp}$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $M = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots) \in l_2, x_1+x_2=0\}$. Find $M^{\perp}$. Find the decomposition $l_2=M \oplus M^{\perp}$.

I think that the orthogonal subspace is $\{(c, c, 0, 0, 0, ...), \text{c is a real number}\}$. An inner product of this and any element from $M$ is $cx_1 + cx_2=c(x1+x2)=0$ since $x_1 = -x_2$. I'm not sure what to do from here.

Comment: Your candidate subspace is clearly contained in $M^\perp$, as you have shown. Next you need to show that it's all of $M^\perp$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $v$ for the element $(1,1,0,0,\dotsc)$.

It spans a one-dimensional subspace $V=\Bbb R v$ of $\ell^2$, which is just the space you wrote down.

Clearly, your $M$ is simply defined as all vectors orthogonal to $v$, hence is just $V^\perp$.

Therefore we have $M^\perp= (V^\perp)^\perp=V$. The latter equality holds because $\ell^2$ is a Hilbert space, and $V$ is a closed subspace (being finite dimensional).

Comment: What is the decomposition $l_2=M \oplus M^{\perp}$?

Comment: It's $(x_1,x_2,\dotsc)=(\frac{x_1-x_2}2,\frac{x_2-x_1}2,x_3,\dotsc)+(\frac{x_1+x_2}2,\frac{x_1+x_2}2,0,\dotsc)$.